# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/concurrent/ReadWriteLockSync

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I have a SpringBoot application running with java8. It runs well but sometimes it starts throwing following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/concurrent/ReadWriteLockSync
at net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore$LockProvider.getSyncForKey(MemoryStore.java:1038)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.tryRemoveImmediately(Cache.java:2170)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1756)
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.lookup(EhCacheCache.java:142)
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.get(EhCacheCache.java:67)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:527)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:492)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:374)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:316)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you some feedback on my solution?

Answer (score 3):

EhCache changed package name between version 2 an 3.

`net.sf.ehcache` refers to package in EhCache2 (your application is trying to find this version)

`org.ehcache` refers to new EhCache3

It could be that you have code working with EhCache2 and now has lost dependency. This happens, for example, if you try to update `Spring Boot 1.5` to `Spring Boot 2`

To make a further test try to force EhCache2 in your `pom.xml` with the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when class is available at compile time and program was compiled and linked successfully but class goes missing during runtime.

Possible solution:

Here you are using `EhCache` and so you might have some *dependency* for that. Copy that `EhCache` `jar` from repository to your project folder (may be `lib` folder that you can add to `build path`). Now you are explicitly giving `jar` file so you can either comment corresponding dependency or make its scope provided.

Now you can try and see if you get the error again. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as stated application runs successfully but say after few hours/day or even months it start throwing this error. 

And Everything my code including the dependencies exist within single jar file.

Comment: so the problem is: it throws error even if you don't re-run the application. After running it, works perfectly for some time and then gives error. is it?

Comment: It starts throwing error all of sudden and if I restart error goes away. So don't know what is the reason behind this.

Comment: There is a possibility that only in some scenario your code is using that particular class and when that scenario occurs, you get the exception. So you can debug in that way. Try to find which code is causing this and then try to find when (not in terms of time but in terms of test case) that code is executed.  So if result is positive then jar (or at least class) is missing. also make sure you are using best suitable version of the jar.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Error is with Ehcache and it is not an isolated code which gets invoked rarely each and every request go through it. I am looking into it   and will share my findings